# Generate a random, non-repeating subset of possible permutations in R

Tags: r, permutation

Given `p` discrete variables, I would like to select randomly, `k` of their possible permutations. 
In other words, for variables `a` in `{0,1}` and `b` in `{1,2,3}`, two random permutations would be 
`[0,2]` and `[1,3]`.

I would like to generate these without first generating a table of all possible permutations because to do that will become cumbersome as the number of variables and the values they can take increase. The catch is that I want to do this without getting repeats. The Code I found [here](https://twitter.com/joshua_ulrich/statuses/243339556785618944) comes close:

```
x <- sample.int (2, m*n, TRUE)-1L
dim(x) <- c(m,n)
```

I realize that for `values > 2`, I can reduce this to a matrix of binary values, so restricting to solving this problem for binary variables would be enough.

Comment: I don't really see where you have *permutations*. Do you want to sample one possible realization from each of your discrete variables with no repetition? If not, could you clarify where the permutations come in?

Comment: That code does not look applicable to the problem. It sets 'replace' to TRUE and you are demanding these _not_ repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you need. It will take the permutations per variable instead of as a whole. This is technically the same, but I believe it would speed things up.

```
a <- 1:100
b <- 1:100
c <- 1:100

yourdatamatrix <- cbind(a, b, c)
```

Now we have some data, here comes the function:

```
PermutationFunction <- function (data, k) {

  # creating matrix: amount of variables * amount of permutations
  permutations <- matrix(1:(k * length(data[1,])), nrow=k) 
  row <- NULL

  # Output will have as many columns as there are variables.
  for (i in 1:length(data[1,])) {
   permutations[ ,i] <- sample(data[ , i], k, replace=FALSE)
  }
  permutations
}

PermutationFunction(yourdatamatrix, k = 10)
```

Time check (40 variables each with 10000 values, taking 5000):

```
system.time(PermutationFunction(yourdatamatrix, 5000))

> system.time(PermutationFunction(yourdatamatrix, 5000))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.05
```

Comment: FYI: As the number of variables increases, this will get very, very slow.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, please never again use, nor suggest to another that they should grow an object at each iteration with `cbind()` in R. It is an abomination and leads one to think R is slow when it is just the user being boneheaded.

Comment: What would your suggestion be?

Comment: Allocate enough storage first; you know how many columns there will be as that is the limit for `i` and `k` gives you the number of rows. Allocate a matrix of that size and then fill in each column via `combinations[, i] <- column` where I changed `permutations` for the same of @DWin's sensibilities ;-)

Comment: I actually tried `permutations[ ,i]` but it gave me an error of something like "not good size", that is, trying to fit 10 items there it choked on it. Is it the predefining the size of the matrix?

Comment: Arrrgh. These are NOT 'permutations'. They are 'combinations'.

Comment: @DWin I see what you mean, though when you are talking about `k` random permutations, I think we come back to combinations?

Comment: If he wanted to list all permutations then it would indeed be a completely different story?

Comment: A permutation is a draw from within one set. A combination is a draw of a tuple from two sets. Please look this up. These are well-defined mathematical terms.

Comment: Hate to refer to wiki, but I do believe he didn't so strongly violate that this thread needs to be full of it. From wiki: "For example, there are six permutations of the set {1,2,3}, namely (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), and (3,2,1).". In that sense, wouldn't it be okay to say to get `k` random permutations?

Comment: Your example was a permutation. His example was a combination.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to do all possible permutations, but it's not actually that cumbersome. Just use expand.grid() and sample from the result. For example:

```
a <- c(0,1)
b <- c(1,2,3)
combinations <- expand.grid(a,b)

k <- 2
combinations[sample(nrow(combinations),k),]
```

This will produce

```
  Var1 Var2
2    1    1
5    0    3
```

Comment: Please don't perpetuate or reinforce the OP's misuse of the word "permutations"

Comment: @DWin or add the line `permutations<-rbind(permutations,permutations[,c(2,1)])`  :-)

Comment: If the proper term: "combinations" had been used, then the search for the right function `combn` would have been much more efficient. If you are not excessively concerned about space, then just storing an index into the output of `combn(a,b,k)` would be possible. It will reduce the storage requirements at the cost of increasing processing cost at the output stage.

Comment: @DWin I'll edit my answer to remove the word "permutation." Can you explain how you would do the same with `combn()`?

Comment: To generate the k-th item from the set of combinations of two vectors: `combn(a,b, 2)[ , k]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at an answer:

First,  Set k to the number of combinations you want to generate

```
k <- 6

# Store your "p discrete variables" as a list (in this case I've arbitrarily made 4)

variables <- list(a = 1:5, b = 3:12, c = 5:14, d = 7:20)

# Generate a matrix with combinations as rows and each column corresponding to a variable

combinations <- matrix( sapply(variables, sample, 1), 
                        ncol = length(variables), 
                        dimnames = list( NULL , names(variables))

                        )

# Compute combinations until you have generated k that are unique

while(nrow(combinations) < k){

comb.new <- sapply(variables, sample, 1)

combinations <- unique(rbind(combinations, comb.new))

}

rownames(combinations) <- NULL
```

I know it isn't very pretty, but it seems to work !  It also has the advantage of not requiring your discrete variables to be of the same length and computes unique COMBINATIONS as oppose to just selecting unique elements from each variable.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, please never again use, nor suggest to another that they should grow an object at each iteration with `rbind()` in R. It is an abomination and leads one to think R is slow when it is just the user being boneheaded.

Comment: Hey Gavin, I am new to R and was just giving the answer a shot.  Usually I just populate pre-existing objects if I can define their size beforehand.  If you have one, I'd be really interested in your recommendation, in the context of this problem, for an answer that doesn't involve expanding an object.

Comment: See the comment to @Dualinitiy's Answer. A bit more difficult in your case as you don't know how many iterations you will end up doing. However, you could allocate say N iterations worth, fill in that matrix and when you've filled it all in but haven't finished iterating, allocate another N rows and carry on filling in. That way you only do a few copy/enlarge/replace operations, not one per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

(Agreeing with Kolassa's critique of your terminology.) If the problem is limited to sets of at most 16 in each set then you could save each sample as a single 4 byte integer (as all versions of R prior to the upcoming R 3.0 have done) with the first selection as bits in the lowest 2 bytes and the second selection in the upper order 2 bytes. You would add up 2^index[i] where where the "index"'s were the positions. If you want code you must first offer coded example cases.