# R - Randomly sample from a matrix using a distribution to denote the number of zeros in each column - stratified sampling

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, random, dplyr

I am trying to randomly sample from a matrix (*b* below) but I want the resulting matrix of samples to have a proportion of zeros in each column equal to that of another matrix (*a* below). I am trying to use `sample()` function to do this but I'm not having much joy. Some reproducible code is below which will hopefully explain my problem:

---

EDIT: Just to mention I don't want any rows augmented or edited but instead the random sampling from `b` to be done such that the resulting matrix; `b_sample` will approximately have an equal distribution of zeros to `a`

---

```
set.seed(1234)
# matrix a is the matrix that holds the distribution of zeros I want to match
a <- matrix(as.integer(rexp(200, rate=.1)), ncol=20)
# matrix b is the matrix to be sampled from 
b <- matrix(as.integer(rexp(2000, rate=.1)), ncol=20)
```

a looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6    0    6    1   22
[2,]   19    6    0   23   19
[3,]    8   22    8    5    0
[4,]   24   17   28    3    0
```

b looks like:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1   10    5    9
 [2,]   26    1    3    2    2
 [3,]    4    8    3    0    0
 [4,]    2   10   35    3   11
 [5,]    1    3   16    0    6
 [6,]    2    4    2   16    2
 [7,]    3   18   13    6   17
 [8,]    0    2    9    0   13
 [9,]    2   15    6   27   30
[10,]    1    2    7    9   15
[11,]   13    0    5    1    2
[12,]   18   12    9   27   33
[13,]    0   20    3   18    1
[14,]    5    7    7   16    4
[15,]    5    6    4    5    2
[16,]    0    7    5   10    7
[17,]    3   20    5   14   34
[18,]   28    0   10    5    8
[19,]   33    0    2    6   13
[20,]    7   28    0   11    8
```

I extract the distribution of zeros in each column of `a` to use in the sampling

```
dist<-apply(a,2, function(x) sum(x!=0)/length(x)) 
dist
[1] 1.00 0.75 0.75 1.00 0.50
```

I then go on to try and sample from `b` to hold the same number of rows as a

```
b_sample<-b[sample(x=nrow(b),
                   size=4,
                   replace=F
                   )
            ,]
```

This will work but I want the `b_sample` to to have the same proportion of zeros in each column as `a`. I have tried to do this

```
b_sample<-b[sample(x=nrow(b),
                   size=4,
                   replace=F,
                   prob=dist
                   )
            ,]
```

but I get an error:

```
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

I am not sure if I have the format wrong to do this or is the `sample()` function not the correction function at all to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT 2: Update below

---

I have found a way to sample from `b` and keep the proportions of zeros in the resulting `b_sample` the same as the original `b`. This is not what I am trying to get, I want the proportions to be equal to that in `a` but it might give a better idea of what I want to do. See below for a development on the above example

First I made `b` into a dataframe and indexed the rows to make use of `dplyr` and `groupby()`

```
b_df<-as.data.frame(b)
b_df <- b_df %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% #create row number
  select(n, everything()) # put row number at the front of the dataset
b_df
    n V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1   1 19  1 29  2  9
2   2  7 20  1  3  9
3   3  3 25  8  9 22
4   4  9  0 20  9  0
5   5  2 12 14  4  2
6   6 10 22  9  1  9
7   7  0  9 16  1  4
8   8  3  3 14 23  2
9   9  7  0  7  1  0
10 10  9  0 26  2  6
11 11  4 19  0  2  6
12 12  0  2  1  7  4
13 13 16 16 25  2  3
14 14  0  1  1  7  9
15 15  8 14  0  9  5
16 16  0 14  9  5  0
17 17 43 27 14  1  4
18 18  9  0 13  4  9
19 19  0  8  3  9 13
20 20 34 36  1  7 20
```

I then create a binary dataframe to indicate if each cell has a 0 or a value

```
b_df_0[,-1]<-as.data.frame(lapply(b_df[,-1],function(x) x==0))
b_df_0
    n    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1   1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2   2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3   3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4   4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5   5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6   6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7   7  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
8   8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
9   9 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
10 10 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
11 11 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
12 12  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
13 13 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
14 14  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
15 15 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
16 16  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
17 17 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
18 18 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
19 19  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
20 20 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I then use `group_by` and `sample_frac` from `dplyr` to sample from `b` to equal the number of samples in `a`.

```
proportion <- nrow(a)/nrow(b)
sample <- b_df_0 %>%
  group_by(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5) %>% #any number of variables you wish to partition by proportionally
  sample_frac(proportion) # proportion of the original df you wish to sample

b_df[b_df$n %in% sample$n,]
#The above approach would work if you can get a proportions = b proportions
    n V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
2   2  7 20  1  3  9
19 19  0  8  3  9 13
20 20 34 36  1  7 20
```

This approach is not what I want however as the proportions are based on `b` when I want them to be based on `a`. Any help on how to do this would be amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to try and down-sample a large matrix to the size of a smaller matrix whilst also ensuring the proportion of zeros for each variable in the down-sampled matrix are equal to that of the smaller matrix.

So after days of research I have found a method to solve the problem I was having without using any predefined function to do the heavy lifting. As it turned out, this was a problem of permutations and, as I painfully figured out, as the number of rows in the matrix I needed to sample from `b` and the number of rows in the matrix I need to down-sample to the size of `a` increased, the problem became impossible to computationally compute. For example if the matrix I'm trying to sample from contained 200 rows and the matrix size I'm trying to down-sample to is 20, this gives n!/(n-r)! permutations or in r

```
> factorial(200)/factorial(200-20)
[1] NaN
```

This problem of the size of the number of permutations eats computational power and memory and has been well covered in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261955/generate-a-random-non-repeating-subset-of-possible-permutations-in-r/14263339). So, in the interests of time and memory, I obviously couldn't check every permutation. I decided to do two things to get around this; firstly, I would only check a proportion of permutations that give me a 95% chance of getting one permutation in the top 5% of solutions (I define top here as having the best approximation of zero distributions to `a`) and secondly, I would stop early if I found a solution where every variable's zero distribution was within 0.05 of `a`. The code below walks through the solution:

First let's create the matrix to sample from `b` and the matrix to get the size and zero distribution to downsample to `a`

```
set.seed(1234)
# matrix a is the matrix that holds the distribution of zeros I want to match
a <- matrix(as.integer(rexp(200, rate=.1)), ncol=20)
# matrix b is the matrix to be sampled from 
b <- matrix(as.integer(rexp(2000, rate=.1)), ncol=20)
```

Next I work out the distribution of zeros I am trying to replicate

```
zero_dist_to_replicate<-apply(a,2, function(x) 
> zero_dist_to_replicate
 [1] 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.6 0.7 0.9 1.0 0.8 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0 0.9
```

Next I am creating variables to keep a count of permutations checked and their errors

```
  perms_used <- list()
  error <- vector()
  answer <- matrix()
```

To work out how many random samples from `b` I need to take to get a permutation in the top 5%, 95% of the time I use

```
ceiling(log(1-0.95)/log(1-0.05))
[1] 59
```

Now I run a while loop that randomly samples from `b` and checks if my second condition from above is met if it isn't I store the permutation and the associated error and continue until I find one that meets the second condition or try 59 conditions. If I try 59 then I return the one with the closest zero distribution to `a`

```
counter<-1
while(counter < 59){
  perm <- NULL
  #Keep picking random permutations until you find one that hasn't been checked before
  while(is.null(perm) || perm %in% perms_used){
    #sample used to generate random numbers to pick rows from b, 
    #-1 and +1 used so random number picked doesn't include 0
    perm <- sample((n-1),num_vars,replace=T)+1
   }
   subsample_set <- b[perm,]
   #check distribution of zeros of this permutation
   subsample_set_dist <- apply(subsample_set,2, function(x) sum(x!=0)/length(x))
   #if the permuted subsample's distribution of zeros is within .05 
   #for each variable of other matrix end early
   diff <- abs(subsample_set_dist-zero_dist_to_replicate)
   if(all(diff <= 0.05)==T){
      answer <- subsample_set
      break
   }
    #getting the sum of the error across all variables
    error[counter]<-sum(diff)
    perms_used[[counter]]<-perm
    counter = counter+1
  }
  if(all(is.na(answer))){
   #return first row with the minimum error
   best_subsample<-perms_used[which(error == min(error))]
   answer <- matrix_to_sample[best_subsample[[1]],])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If p is the proportion of 0s in a column of A and b_rows is the number of rows in B.

Example for column j of B:

B[sample(1:b_rows,b_rows*p),j]=0

Comment: Hey Javier, sorry I should have mentioned I don't want to augment the rows in any way, so I just want the sampling to be done in such a way so that the distributions of zeros in each column approximate to the distribution of the other matrix. I will update my question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The issue is I don't want to manipulate the values in any row, I want to sample rows from b that will give the distribution.

Comment: The column is the same size, but with randomly located rows now being 0. It works if B columns have no zeros. In case it has zeros already, you can use B[sample(which(B[,j]!=0),b_rows*p-sum(B[,j]==0)),j]=0

Comment: Sorry if that's not what you need. If you show the example of the matrix you want to obtain when sampling from B, may be I can help!.

Comment: That's no problem! However, I don't want to manually manipulate `b_sample` to get the proportion of zeros the same as `a`. I want it to be done intrinsically in the sampling as I want to use this approach multiple times so I don't think showing what combination of rows, from `b`, `b_sample` could hold would be of benefit. I'm more so looking for another function or a use of sample() to do this.